# Upgrade to 12.04 LTS from 11.10

Tags: upgrade

I initiated an upgrade to 12.04 from 11.10.  The upgrade manager had completed package download and installation but was killed before the cleanup phase started.  Ubuntu 12.04 is now loaded but occassional errors exist.  Should I do a reinstall from scratch or is there a way to reactivate the update manager to properly complete the installation?

Thanks,
...tom

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

Tom, you could also make sure everything finished installing.. Does running

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

cause anything to happen? Are you able to install stuff now? You may also try removing and re-installing the ubuntu-desktop meta-package and see if everything is installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Still, without knowing what these "errors" you speak of are, nor the state of your apt or machine it's hard to know what else to recommend for you outside of a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

The missed cleanup phase shouldn't cause any errors but, just to be safe, you can run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

which will uninstall unneeded packages. This is probably most of what the cleanup phase was about to do before it exited.

If your problem persists, you may want to consider a full reinstall. Even if the upgrade had fully completed, people tend to report that 'clean installs' are faster and more stable than upgrades. I've personally never had a clean install go wrong, nor an upgrade go perfectly right, although many people claim it works fine for them.